# Downloading images from a txt containing the links in python

Tags: python, urllib

```
import urllib.request
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
c = 0
f = open('urls.txt','r')
links = f.readlines()
r = len(links)
print(r)
for i in range(len(links)):
    links[i] = links[i][:-1]


try:
    for i in range(r):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(links[i],'dosa\{}.jpg'.format(c))
        c+=1
        print("done downloading {}.jpg".format(c))
except:
    pass
f.close()
```

I wrote the above code to download a set of images whose URL's are in a text  file.
It contains 400 links, but the download stops after 25 downloads

```
400
done downloading 1.jpg
done downloading 2.jpg
done downloading 3.jpg
done downloading 4.jpg
done downloading 5.jpg
done downloading 6.jpg
done downloading 7.jpg
done downloading 8.jpg
done downloading 9.jpg
done downloading 10.jpg
done downloading 11.jpg
done downloading 12.jpg
done downloading 13.jpg
done downloading 14.jpg
done downloading 15.jpg
done downloading 16.jpg
done downloading 17.jpg
done downloading 18.jpg
done downloading 19.jpg
done downloading 20.jpg
done downloading 21.jpg
done downloading 22.jpg
done downloading 23.jpg
done downloading 24.jpg
done downloading 25.jpg
```

I also tried adding a continue after the 24th downloadd, but nothing seems to work.

The exception gives this error :

```
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: and if you increase timeout's value, does more of the files get downloaded? You may end up forking the process (and use wait to delay downloads: do not trigger all of them at the same time) https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: `except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
` to get more info